# css text-decoration:none; in chrome with <a> inside of <div>

Tags: html, css, text-decorations

```
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="www.facebook.com">Like us on Facebook!</a>
        <a href="www.youtube.com">Check our YT channel!</a>
        <a href="www.codecademy.com">This is our website!</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

in css:

```
a:link{
text-decoration:none;
color:#008b45;
}
a:hover{
color:#00ff00;
}
a:visited{
color:#ee9a00;
}
```

I can't seem to get this fixed in Chrome. I used Opera and Mozilla and it works just fine. I know that I can't use "a" or ol/ul inside of tag like span but it should work inside of . I don't get it at all. And it's not like block element(div) is inside an inline element (a). So this should be working as far as I know. But I'm here because apparently I don't know that much. And sorry if this is a duplicate, but I really don't know how to fix this anymore.

Comment: It's working for me... Is there other code that's affecting the links?

Answer (score 0):

Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:link, the `:link` pseudo-class only affects `<a>` tags that have *not* been visited. So if you haven't ever visited those sites, you shouldn't see the underline.

It sounds like the problem is that the styles inside `a:link` aren't working for you? If that's the case, and you want them to be your default styles, just make that

```
a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#008b45;
}
```